# What are the effects of Civilization V responses to other leaders?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

Some responses seem not to have any effect reflected in the relationship details. Some examples:

When they admonish you about making friends with one of their enemies:

- Get over it.
- We're sorry this has created a divide between us.

When you are competing for the favor of city-states:

- Get over it.
- We're sorry this has created a divide between us.

When they become hostile and insult you:

- You'll pay for this in time.
- Very well.

When you bully a city state under their protection:

- We'll leave them alone from now on.
- Our affairs are none of your business.

Does your choice of response to these situations have any effect?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "angry" response (ie "Get over it.") will produce a more negative relationship hit than the apologetic one.  In practice, though, I find the AI tends to hate me either way.

Comment: I second that opinion, it seems no matter how I respond they always take it negatively and eventually denounce and attack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the exception of diplomatic responses that can be taken as promises and some of the ones relating to city-states, they're just flavor text.

The "promise" ones are stuff like you saying you aren't planning to invade or expand near them. Breaking promises makes *all* civilizations trust you less, not just the one that you're talking to.

The city-state ones that effect things are ones like where they attack a city-state under your protection and you can choose to ignore it or stand firm. I believe hovering over the options actually tells you, in this case, what they do.

There's some more information on this dynamic on the [civ fanatics forum](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=457990).

Answer (score -1):

I think once you pass a measured level of dominance your responses become irrelevant to their play; at some threshold your responses become overruled by your level of competitiveness in the field of play.

Responding with "Get over it" will certainly entrench hostility but, depending on your relative score or position at the time, a more lenient response pales into insignificance to the threat you pose.  Often if you're a mile ahead, or even just in-the-game, they'll hate you for that simple fact alone.

Comment: Welcome to gaming.SE. Your response could be improved by adding formulas or a link to support your statement.

Comment: Agreed. Any data or source code to support this?

Comment: Nope, none whatsoever.