# Effects of your response to Denoucing?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Does your response to being denounced have an effect? If so, what effect?

- You'll pay for this
- Very well

Does this change between Vanilla, G&K, and BNW (in over-all effect or minor adjustments)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the effects of Civilization V responses to other leaders?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93582/what-are-the-effects-of-civilization-v-responses-to-other-leaders)

Comment: My only concern in regards to the close is that the answers to that question do not answer my question. The question is contained it the other, but is never actually answered (at least not clearly, imo). Whether that actually changes anything I wouldn't know.

Comment: @Shelby115 if the other question doesn't answer your question, then this should stay open.

Comment: "With the exception of diplomatic responses that can be taken as promises and some of the ones relating to city-states, they're just flavor text.". This looks answered perfectly well in the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These have no effect, its just a flavor/role playing choice.

Comment: That's a rather disappointing answer. Not that it's your fault or anything. I hate it when games make it look like you have a choice/effect when you really don't.

Comment: @Shelby115 Well, if you think about it, there is not much in terms of game mechanics that the game can offer here. The only thing that they could have added is to declare war instantly. But the action was already done, they already denounced you. So what effect could a response have? You can denounce back or just attack them, which may prove them right in the end.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness They could have easily made up some mechanic where you vow vengence on their puny empire (You'll pay for this) which ruins your relationship further. Secondly, they could have made a counter-denouncing where you denounce them back (Not saying this is a good idea, but it is an idea). There's always something they could have done. It's just a matter of someone coming up with it.

Comment: This is one of the better mods for denouncements. http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=292535662

Answer (score 0):

I always thought it was based on their "Anger" level with you. You can see it in the right hand nav under the world icon. You can also see this based on the history notes under the respective countries. If there is a lot of red text like, "You angered X country," "They caught you spying," or "You denounced them," it means they'll probably say "You'll pay for this" vs "Very well."